# Wire with SubSurf doesn't follow surface in Edit mode

Tags: mesh, modifiers, subdivision-surface, wireframe

How do I smooth the grid along the mesh? I've been looking for the answer all day and I couldn't find anything.

[image]

Comment: Omg! Thank you!

Comment: Do note that generally it is not recommended to modify the geometry this way because you will mangle the actual underlying geometry, even if the subdivided one looks fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the triangle with the vertices in the [SubSurf modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html) panel:

[image]
[image]

You do not always want to have it enabled in *Edit mode* since it can be sometimes quite confusing moving vertices affected by modifier so if you have difficulties disable it to check your current geometry.